# Как присвоить данные из Promise внешней переменной?

Tags: javascript, json, promise, fetch

У меня есть json-файл с таким вот объектом:

```
{
    "0": "a",
    "1": "b",
    "2": "c",
    "3": "d",
}
```

Есть внешняя переменная и через fetch я делаю GET запрос:

```
let foo;

const get = async (url) => {
    let result = await fetch(url);
    return await result.json();
}

get('Какой-то url-адрес')
.then(response => {
    const bar = response[0]; - Например.
    console.log(bar); - Выводит в консоль.
);
```

Как присвоить весь response или отдельные значения по ключу во внешнюю переменную foo?

Comment: Прямо так и присвоить: `foo = bar;`

Comment: Да? А теперь выведи в консоль внешнюю переменную и посмотри, что покажет. Только за пределами промиса. Получается undefined. Как вытащить данные во внешнюю переменную из промиса и потом работать с ними? Как присваивать одни переменные другим я и так знаю.

Comment: Никак, дождаться получения данных возможно только в промисе или после await.

Comment: Присвоение во внешнюю переменную вполне себе работает — если вы сделаете console.log(foo) **внутри промиса**, то увидите, что всё прекрасно присвоилось.

Comment: Я бы переписал код без then используя try catch